# Is projection on a finite dimensional subspace of a banach space linear?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

My question is simple. It is known that if $M$ is a finite dimensional subspace of a banach space $X$, then for any $x$ there exists $v$ in $M$ such that $|v-x|=d(x,M)$.
My question is - is this $v$ unique? If so, is the correspondence $x\mapsto v$ linear? I can't seem to prove any one of these... I'm getting nowhere with mere triangle inequalities, so help or references will be helpful.

Comment: If $X$ is strictly convex then such a point is indeed unique (such sets that admit such unique best approximations are called Chebyshev). In fact, a Banach space is reflexive and strictly convex if and only if every closed and convex of its subset is Chebyshev.  The corresponding map (a.k.a. the metric projection onto $M$) is in general nonlinear. In fact, if each metric projection onto a closed subspace of a Banach space $X$ is linear, then $X$ is (isomorphic to) a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you, I was getting the feeling it is not true...